# Taxonomy autocomplete widget with term depth settings

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms, search

Is there a module (or custom code) to implement a widget for taxonomy autocomplete (>=1k terms) having term depth settings? 
Settings could be like to control term level variable depth, rules and permissions integration, etc. in order to let (&control) users classify its own content in a clean ui?

I made some research in this amazing site (and Google) reading every post concerning this matter with little luck (tags: autocomplete, add/edit nodes, widgets, taxonomy, D7)

I have tried the following outstanding modules:
    Heriatrical select,
    Autocomplete deluxe,
    Autocomplete hieratical widges,
    Select with style,
    Taxonomy autocomplete,
Autocomplete Widgets for Text and Number Fields,
Taxonomy Autocomplete Settings,
Hierarchical Select,
Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget,
Search Autocomplete,
Taxonomy Access Control,
Simple hieratical select,
Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete (best one, but no settings for depth)

None of them render what I am looking for; I’m kind of newbie with Drupal and coding and may be missing another approach like node reference or something similar;  Solr or Acquia search add any advantage?  I will be very pleased if you can give me some help. 
Thanks in advance DRUPAL Friends, greetings from Mexico.

Comment: There is a new module called Client-side hierarchical (https://www.drupal.org/project/cshs) that solves some tasks, does not have autocomplete, but it is the best i found.